# Managing Profiles StarTeam 2008

Tags: starteam

We are using star team to manage a repository with code bases both in UNIX and in windows. The way we used to manage such codebases with Star Team 2005 was by keeping a profile for windows and UNIX. The profiles defined the line endings and the checkout directory. Now that StarTeam has been updated to 2008, I have noticed that this feature has either disappeared or has been renamed.  How can I do the same using StarTeam 2008?

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the StarTeam Cross Platform Client and go to Tools/Personal Options and then the File tab, you'll see options for EOL settings.